# Nhibernate, after insert, selecting the table results are old

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, nhibernate

Using MS VS 2012, C#.net, Nhibernate.

Im inserting a new row.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddQuestion(ModuleAddQuestionModel model)
    {
        if (!_moServices.Authoriser.Authorise(AcademyPermissions.AccessDeveloperArea))
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();

        if (model == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        int modelId = 0;
        var module = _moduleService.GetModule(model.ModuleId);
        // if null
        
        if(model != null)
        {
            modelId = model.ModuleId;
        }
        
        var addQuestion = new Question()
        {
            Text = model.Question,
            QuestionType = model.QuestionType,
            Published = model.Published,
            Country = module.Country,
            Module = module
        };

        _moduleService.SaveQuestion(addQuestion);
        
        
        return RedirectToAction(
            "Edit",
            "Module",
            new { Id = modelId }
            );
    }
```

redirect calls

```
public ActionResult Edit(int Id) {
        if (!_moServices.Authoriser.Authorise(AcademyPermissions.AccessDeveloperArea))
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();

        var module = _moduleService.GetModule(Id);
        if(module == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        var model = new ModuleEditModel {
            Id = module.Id,
            Name = module.Name,
            Questions = module.Questions
                .Where(x => !x.Deleted)
                .Select(x => new ModuleEditModel.ModuleQuestionModel {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Question = x.Text
                }).ToList(),
            Videos = module.Videos.Select(x => new ModuleEditModel.ModuleVideoModel {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Title = x.Name
                }).ToList()
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

the view displays the results, it should display a list that has the new row, but doesn't, even after f5.  I suspect it was caching, but we don't have any caching involved for this whole procedure. Next step was to look into Nhibernate and caching.

the has the 2 relevent methods

```
public Module GetModule(int id) {
        _moduleRepository.Flush();
        return _moduleRepository.Get(id);
    }

public void SaveQuestion(Question question) {
        if (question.Id > 0)
            UpdateQuestion(question);
        else
            InsertQuestion(question);
    }

    public void InsertQuestion(Question question) {
        _questionRepository.Create(question);
        _questionRepository.Flush();
        _signals.Trigger(ModuleSignalChanged);
    }
```

the `.flush` command was recently added by me to see if that would help clear the results, but didn't change anything.

looked into `Isession.Clear();` but as i understand in our cms this lives outside the scope.

Im wondering what the issue is here, was i on the right tract? is this a NHibernate caching issue? Can anyone offer a solution?

If you require any additional information let me know.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

Yes the insert does populate the Database (MS SQL server 2008)

It appears after a few minutes, if one refreshes the page, the new record is displayed.

Comment: Yes i dont generate the new question ID, i let the server do that.
The edit action calls to the service to GetModule by the module ID.
Module ID is taken from the models ModuleID that was passed. Yeh if the Model is null for whatever reason it just passses in 0 as the id which doesnt bring back any data and would instead show a blank list. Does this help?

Comment: My point is, that the ID used for redirection, is later used in a call `GetQuestion(Id)`... if that would not be the correct one, the question would not be found correctly. I would expect that instead of this void call `_moduleService.SaveQuestion(addQuestion);` we will see `var questionId = ...` and that should be passed into *redirect*.

Comment: just relized ive posted the wrong action xD no wonder i didnt understand, 2 seconds ill update, sorry for that

Comment: Also, NHibernate works as you'd expect. So, unless there is cache used explicitly... it won't be cached - because I expect you instantiate the `ISession` per request. Maybe show more of your code...

Comment: Im not too sure about the ISession, i think it may live inside the CMS infrastructure that I haven't fiddled with. Unless I've misunderstood you (probably have).  As for the "repository" that are used to .create and .flush there all instantiated via the constructor if the service.  Does this help?

Comment: do suspect the issue lies within the CMS? im hoping it isnt hehe

Comment: Well, what I also see here is this assignment when building the question: `Module = module`. I would suggest also to extend it with next call like `module.Questions.Add(question)`. If the module is cached, then this will solve the issue ;)

Comment: hmmmmm ill try that and let you know! what is the .Add(question) variable?  i dont see it in the action i created?

Comment: Isession is within the Repository class, just relized that going through, but its within the CMS, Id rather not change the core, is there a way to bring the Isession into the scope of my actions or services?

Comment: Well, as I said above, this is the essential feature. YOu should observe the doc to your CMS ... there must be a way how to set session lifetime cycle... sorry, I do not have better answer.. good luck ;)

Comment: yeh extending forced the cache it seems.  Also i would LOVE a doc for the CMS, but its and in house CMS which has no documentation *shudders* hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the answer

```
var addQuestion = new Question()
        {
            Text = model.Question,
            QuestionType = model.QuestionType,
            Published = model.Published,
            Country = module.Country,
            Module = module
        };

        module.Questions.Add(addQuestion);
        _moduleService.UpdateModule(module);
```

Instead of trying to insert a question, i updated the module instead that question is a child element of. This i assume cascades due to the relationship which forces nhibernate to clear cache and check the DB.

I cant confirm this, but this appears to at least solve this problem, if anyone can enlighten me as to why the previous method hasn't worked, ill swap my confirmed answer